# Error starting class in FragmentActivity (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id)

Tags: android, android-fragments, bluetooth, android-fragmentactivity

I am building an app that has a game and communicates game information to a second device for wireless multiplayer via Bluetooth. Right now I am trying to put the Bluetooth and game classes in a FragmentActivity class to allow for seamless Bluetooth access while the game is being played. I am able to successfully get the game to load through the fragment but for some reason the Bluetooth porting throws an error. I have tried using activity.setContentView() and the inflater.inflate, what I normally use but I still get the persistent errors. Can someone show me how to fix my problem> I have included the offending code and the error log output.

```
07-30 13:27:25.225  15076-15076/com.example.android.BluetoothChat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.BluetoothChat/com.example.android.BluetoothChat.FragmentHolder}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f060001 for fragment BluetoothChat{41b2d4e0 #1 id=0x7f060001}
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f060001 for fragment BluetoothChat{41b2d4e0 #1 id=0x7f060001}
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:823)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5017)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2032)
        ... 11 more
07-30 13:28:51.565  13981-13981/? E/APKInstallReceiver: context = android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@41998db0, intent.getAction() = android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED, intent.getDataString() = package:com.example.android.BluetoothChat
07-30 13:28:51.825  13981-13981/? E/APKInstallReceiver: context = android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@41998db0, intent.getAction() = android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED, intent.getDataString() = package:com.example.android.BluetoothChat
07-30 13:28:56.305  15215-15215/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.BluetoothChat/com.example.android.BluetoothChat.FragmentHolder}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f060001 for fragment BluetoothChat{418a7730 #1 id=0x7f060001}
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f060001 for fragment BluetoothChat{418a7730 #1 id=0x7f060001}
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:823)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5017)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2032)
        ... 11 more



 View view;
    Activity activity;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");
    activity = getActivity();
    // Set up the window layout
//        activity.setContentView(R.layout.main);

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main,
            container, false);



    // Get local Bluetooth adapter
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(activity, StartGame.class));
//            this.finish();

    }
    return view;
}
```

This is the FragmenActivity portion (Not All My code so don't tell me I am missing braces.

```
  public class FragmentHolder extends FragmentActivity {

    public static boolean menuHidden = true;
    public static final int LEFT_FRAG = R.id.fragmentcontainerleft;
    public static final int RIGHT_FRAG = R.id.fragmentcontainerright;
    public static final int BOTTOM_FRAG = R.id.fragmentcontainerbottom;
    Fragment menu, main, top;

    View view;
    Activity activity;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bluetooth_menu_frag);

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();

            //Start transaction
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

            //Create fragments
            menu = new BluetoothChat();
            main = new StartGame();
    //            top = new TopFragment();

            //Add fragments
            transaction.add(RIGHT_FRAG,main);
            transaction.add(LEFT_FRAG,menu );
    //            transaction.add(BOTTOM_FRAG,top);

            transaction.commit();
        }

        if(!menuHidden){
            ScrollView scrollview = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.fragleft);
            scrollview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            FrameLayout menuFrame = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.fragmentcontainerleft);
            menuFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is device in landscape mode?

If so, is the view in the res folder for layout or land-layout?  I have found this to resolve these errors completely.

I think it's a timing issue when Android is looking for the resource.  If the current layout is landscape, it will look there first for the resource and then on to other folders.  It's unfortunate to have to have two copies of the exact same file in the resources, but this is the only way I have found to resolve the issue.